# Navigation list not correctly styled on pages with custom template (missing .current-menu-item)

Tags: menus, navigation

My Wordpress site uses a custom front page (`home.php`). The blog page uses a template (`blog.php`).

However when I visit the blog page the navigation bar does not highligt the current page. This is because the class `.current-menu-item` (and the class `.current_page_item`) are missing from the navigation `li`. This class is correctly included when I visit all other pages that use the default page template.

Here is the template for the blog page:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Blog
*/

// Which page of the blog are we on?
$paged = get_query_var('paged');
query_posts('cat=-0&paged='.$paged);

// make posts print only the first part with a link to rest of the post.
global $more;
$more = 0;

//load index to show blog
load_template(TEMPLATEPATH . '/index.php');

?>
```

I've noticed that if I remove the call to `query_posts` then the nav bar styling works correctly, but the page is left blank.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom navigation menu uses the global `$wp_query` object to figure out what page is the current page and should get that class. `query_posts()` replaces this `$wp_query` object, so the navigation menu can't apply the correct classes.

Why do you use a separate template for this page? If you specify no template, it should use the home template (`home.php` or `index.php`) with the correct posts in the loop, and you should not need your own `query_posts()`.

Comment: Ok, I see you've edited your answer suggesting I don't need a template. You're probably right. In my current setup my front page does not display posts (just a few widgets). I have a separate "news" page which displays the latest blog posts. This is a static page that uses the template blog.php. Is there a more elegant way to achieve the same result?

Comment: The reason I have is setup like this is because I used some example code I found [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/static-front-page-blog#post-618888)

Comment: @Andy: If you rename your `home.php` to `front-page.php`, it will only be used for the static front page, not for the "post index list" at `blog`. You should then not need a special page template for the "fake" blog page. It will use `home.php`, and if it does not exist, the standard `index.php`. It was another question that made me really test this and edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Everything works as it should, and with a simpler implementation than before.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by, Jan `query_posts()` replaces this `$wp_query` object.

So what you can do is use `WP_Query` and store old $wp_query object:

```
$temp = $wp_query;  
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args); 
while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
    Do what you need
endwhile;
$wp_query = $temp;
```

or use a new variable:

```
$loop = new WP_Query($args); 
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    Do what you need
endwhile;
```